# Why isn't my React App working with Strict Mode?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and i'm trying to accomplish a basic to-do list with some Add and Delete buttons.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4lDv.png)

The thing is that after some minutes of not getting why the Delete button wouldn't work (it was deleting all the elements of my array setting it to empty instead of just removing the last one) i decided to remove the Strict Mode tags from Index.js, and surprisingly now it works. But i can't figure out exactly why that happens or whether my code needs to be fixed. Any help would be useful!

edit: I think i found the problem not the reason or solution though:
[after console logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/039A2.png)
as you can see, the first time it renders it works as expected. But the second time it sets the array to an empty array with no reason.

Comment: please do not post code images

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating state in `setItems` in you're `handleDelete` function. In a `<StrictMode>` wrapper, `useState` setters are executed twice, so `.splice()` will be invoked against `items` twice when the delete button is clicked. This is because `prev` in your `setItems` callback and `items` **reference the same array in memory**.

To resolve this, invoke `splice` against a copy instead:

```
setItems((prev) => [...prev].splice(0, prev.length - 1));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i understand i made a mistake by mutating the state myself, but i still don't understand what's going on. If splice is executed twice shouldn't it just delete two elements instead of all of them?

Comment: No because you are splicing `prev.length - 1` amount of elements from index position 0 of the array `prev` points to, always leaving you with 1 element for the second splice